# Total loaded size is not same with real file size on axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I use axios in my react app when uploading file.

To track how much uploaded in real time, I use `onUploadProgress`. And I want to show upload progress in ui progress bar with real uploaded byte size compared with real file size.

But, I found that  totally upload size, extracted from `onUploadProgress` callback function, is not same with the real file size. For example, here is my console.log below.

```
file size:  2151076
loaded: 2151715
```

This gap is really small. But I don't know what cause this difference. Is it caused by Axios? or Browser?
Anyone has idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the file?

Comment: @JaromandaX did you mean file type? It is occurred regardless of file type

Comment: is it always 639 bytes?

Comment: @JaromandaX Nope. This is different according to what file is. And on same file, the gap is always equal.

Comment: it's almost as if the server is saying "the content is x long" but the server is wrong - edit: nevermind, this is an upload - ignore